# Why does the ls instruction in gitbash not show me my c drive?

Tags: bash, command-line, command-line-interface, ls

```
iamth@DESKTOP-TQE8AEJ MINGQ64 ~ (master)
$ cd ..

iamth@DESKTOP-TQE8AEJ MINGQ64 /c/Users
$ cd ../..

iamth@DESKTOP-TQE8AEJ MINGQ64 /
$ ls
LICENSE.txt        cmd/  git-bash.exe*  proc/         unins000.exe*
ReleaseNotes.html  dev/  git-cmd.exe*   tmp/          unins000.msg
bin/               etc/  mingwt64/      unins000.dat  usr/

iamth@DESKTOP-TQE8AEJ MINGQ64 /
$ cd c

iamth@DESKTOP-TQE8AEJ MINGQ64 /c
$
```

I have tried other things, like doing `ls *`, but it will not show up anywhere.

Note, I can navigate to my c drive, but the `ls` instruction does not list it. Why is this, and what can I do about it?

Comment: Consider [Super User](https://superuser.com/) for questions about using software, as opposed to writing software.

Comment: That said -- at some point you're going to end up with "because that's how mingw64 was implemented" as the only available answer. The library was written to emulate UNIX-y semantics where there's a unified filesystem tree on Windows-y systems where no such thing exists.

Comment: (Also, why do you think it's necessary to do anything about it? It's working as designed).

Comment: See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/14122) re: why I replaced the screenshot with a transcription. Please do this yourself in the future.

Comment: BTW, this has been previously discussed on the mingw mailing list: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/10715715/

Comment: For what its worth, I don't think you would see "C" in a list even in CMD.exe (if you used the equivalent `dir` command and you have navigated to the root of the C drive)

Comment: Since it is a directory that I can navigate to, I expected to see it as an option after the ls command. I am not sure I understand why I cannot. Why would this the intended behavior?

Comment: And how can I check for the existence of other directories (e.g. partitions on my drive), if I don't see them? Would this have to do with having access to these partitions? In other words, is the c drive, the only thing I am not seeing?

Comment: Use `df` if you want to see what's available.

Comment: *Why would this [be] the intended behavior?* -- because _some_ way to implement access to non-default drives was needed, but synthesizing artificial directory entries for them would be a bunch of error-prone work (that someone would have to implement) for not much benefit?

Comment: If _you_ want to volunteer to go implement that logic, be my guest.

Comment: So, when I do `cd ..` and go "one level back" from my c drive, am I seeing the whole of my physical drive?

Answer (score -1):

The Git Bash terminal in Windows is a Unix-style shell and does not directly support accessing Windows drives. To access the C drive from Git Bash, you need to mount the C drive in the Git Bash file system. You can do this by running the following command:

```
mount -t drvfs C: /c.
```

After running this command, you should be able to access the C drive by running `ls /c`.

Comment: This is not what the question is about. The OP said: "Note, I can navigate to my c drive, but the ls instruction does not list it." If you know it's there, you can `cd` into it. But `ls` doesn't show it.